# How can I wait until external application is manually closed?

Tags: java, runtime

I want to open an external app from my java code and wait until the user closes the external app, and then continue on with my code.

To undrestand my problem, I want to open a medical image with an external application called weasis and then when the user closes weasis the code will continue and delete image file to protect the patient's privacy

Here is my code :

```
public static void openDicomWeasis (){
    File folder = new File(OutPutResultFolder);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            File fichierSource = new File(listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
            String fichier="C:\\weasis\\"+listOfFiles[i].getName()+".dcm";
            String file=listOfFiles[i].getName()+".dcm";
            File fichierDest= new File(fichier);
            copier(fichierSource,fichierDest);

            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

            try { 
                String query="C:\\Users\\salhi\\Desktop\\projet ath\\dicom viewer\\weasis\\weasis-win32.exe \"$dicom:get -l \'"+fichier+"\'\"";
                final Process p = runtime.exec(query);
                int exit= p.waitFor();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ConnexionPostgres_Retour.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(RadioApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            delete();
        }
    }
}
```

here is my delete method

```
public static void delete(){
    File fichier =new File("C:\\weasis");
    try {
        FileUtils.cleanDirectory(fichier);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RadioApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

my problem is that the method `waitFor()` does not wait as I expect that it should

the process p finishes even though the external app weasis is still opened

My explanation is that the process p does its job which is to open weasis and then it ends, and at that point the process p is not linked to the external app. The process p can not see that the weasis is still opened thats why the `waitFor()` method does not wait as expected.

How can I order java to wait until the user close manually the external app then continue and delete the medical files?

Comment: Is an exception being thrown?

Comment: If you are correct, if the application that you run is in fact a "launching" application where it launches another app, and then moves out of the way, then you may need to find a way to launch the medical imaging application directly yourself in your application.

Comment: there is no exception being thrown

Comment: the medical imaging application is also a java application that uses JRE to launch
Can you please help me to find another way to launch the application and let my java code detect when the application is closed to proceed and delete the files?

Comment: you can find the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350347/runtime-exec-waitfor-not-actually-waiting-for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can wait for the output of the process to finish instead like so:

```
BufferedReader stdOut=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String s;
        while((s=stdOut.readLine())!=null){
          //nothing or print
        }
```

Comment: thank you very much, that was what i needed. 
When adding this code after  "final Process p = runtime.exec(query);" the java code wait until i close the external app then it execute the rest